# Unable to connect with database - MAMP

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, root, mamp

I am using MAMP and Sequel Pro and am unable to connect my database with wordpress for local theme development. In MAMP my lights are green . Inside Sequel Pro, I seem to be able to connect via socket using localhost, root, and my password that I reset in the terminal ( root was not giving me access).
Bu then when I try to load in the browser

```
http://localhost:8888/wordpress/
```

with 'wordpress' as my database name in sequel pro, I get
"Error establishing a database connection"

I changed the MySQL user password in the wp-config file to reflect the password change with no meaningful result:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress'); ( as I assigned in sequel pro)

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

I've been searching all night trying all sorts of avenues with no luck.

I was doing fine with MAMP until I recently upgraded to Pro and was prompted to reset the password....since then, no dice despite efforts to reset in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but in case anyone runs into this via the googles, the solution is to make sure you're pointing to the correct socket.  Sequel Pro by default looks in /tmp/mysql.sock to connect, which is where mysql would be installed if you didn't use MAMP PRO.

In Sequel Pro, connect using a socket and point the socket to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock it should all work peachy.